# low bandwidth on relay

Tags: ubuntu

My relay has dropped all its throughput speed and I cant see what is causing a problem? can anyone offer any pointers?

Relay in question :
https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/6E1DA4C0B0C05FB721B42329C47A20DA22908AEB

Comment: Your relay has been given a low consensus weight by three of the directory authorities. I tested your relay and it's giving me speeds of ~500 KiB/s for a circuit, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. It may be a problem with the bandwidth authorities. Maybe double check that you don't have any outgoing firewall rules as they could cause circuits to fail.

Comment: I had a quick look, ufw in Ubuntu shows that 443 and 9001 are set to allow in from anywhere.. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your relay shows that it's using ports 443 and 80 (not 9001), so you might want to update that. But I don't think that's your consensus weight problem (port 80 is only used for providing directory documents). If no one is able to help here, you might want to ask on the tor-relays mailing list, or #tor-relays on IRC.